# Function and its selector to choose how to export CSV

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

Here is the source code in a page for a user to choose to export a CSV file.

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px">
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-twitter"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> 导出</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-twitter dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/admin/order?_export_=all" target="_blank">全部</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1" target="_blank">当前页</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/order?_export_=selected%3A__rows__" target="_blank" class='export-selected'>选择的行</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The purpose of the code is to choose `当前页` out of 3 options and fire up the export event. Here is the snippet of the code for exporting CSV:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', 
         downloadPath: '/tmp'})
res = await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 60000}),
      page.click('a[href$="/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1"]'),      
    ]);
```

The error is:

```
Error: No node found for selector: a[href$="/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1"]
at assert (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:259:11)
at Frame.click (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:704:5)
at <anonymous>
```

There are 2 questions here. The first is: is `page.click()` right for the purpose? There is `page.select()` which does the similar thing. Second is: what is the correct selector for the 2nd options I would like to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are clicking the dropdown button before clicking the link:

```
await page.click('.btn-twitter.dropdown-toggle');
```

Then, once the link is visible, you can click it using the following selector:

```
await page.click('a[href$="/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1"]');
```

You may need to use [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to wait for the element to be added to the DOM if the element is dynamically generated:

```
await page.waitForSelector('a[href$="/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

`page.click()` is correct if you want to follow the link. `page.select()` is for selecting a value in a select box.

Regarding your query selector, you are missing a closing bracket and quotation marks. It should work like this:

```
page.click('a[href$="/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1"]')
```

Comment: I still error of no node found. Not sure what I am missing. The `page.click` is within a `Promise.all`. See updated the post.